# Decimal place in select statement sql

Tags: sql, select, case, average

I have a perfectly working select statement which I have been using. However I have noticed that it does not return any more than zero decimal places. Which I thought Excel had been factoring out, when copied across, but its not.

I have tried to change the format, but I still get zero decimal places. I have reviewed all posts on here, but as I am using a Case statement as well it is not simple to include.

```
Round(AVG(case when [Duration] > 0 then [Duration] end), 3) as AVGLOS,
```

Any help welcomed as always.

Comment: What is the data type of Duration?

Comment: Your approach seems to be right, but try checking the data types

Comment: you can cast([Duration] as numeric(36,3))

Comment: Data type is an int

Comment: TechGirl - where would I put the cast?

Comment: CAST(Round(AVG(case when [Duration] > 0 then [Duration] end), 3) as numeric(36,3)) as AVGLOS,

Comment: @TechGirl - I think you need the cast *inside* the `AVG`, not outside. Otherwise, it's already computed the average as an `int` and nothing's going to obtain additional decimals afterwards.

Comment: Agreed I was just going to ask, as all I got was 2.00. So where should the cast be inside Damien

Comment: @ HAS >>>So where should the cast be inside<<< I've already showed it to youin my answer. You should use Duration * 1. inside your AVG. But ok, I'll update it CLEARLY

Comment: Agreed I was just going to ask, as all I got was 2.00. So where should the cast be inside Damien_the_unbeliever

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Data type is an int

That is your problem.

The avg of integer values is always integer:

```
   declare @t table (col int);
   insert into @t values (2), (3);

   select avg(col)
   from @t;
----
2
```

So you should manipulate decimals, not integers like this:

```
   declare @t table (col int);
   insert into @t values (2), (3);

   select avg(col * 1.)
   from @t;
---
2.500000
```

So in your case just use this:

```
Round(AVG(case when [Duration] > 0 then [Duration]* 1. end), 3) as AVGLOS
```